# Linux: How to kill a root owned process by parameter's name?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, kill, raspbian

I would like to know how to kill processes owned by the root based on their parameter's information:

```
root      3176  0.0  0.8   3604  2252 ?        S    21:33   0:00 sudo python main.py
root      3191 65.4  4.6  96820 11744 ?        Rl   21:33  10:00 python main.py
```

I am trying like this but no success:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ps aux | grep main.py | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo pkill -u root main.py
```

Comment: This might get a better response over at superuser.se

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pkill would be the simpler approach, you just missed one parameter.

From "man pkill":

```
 -f, --full
          The pattern is normally only matched against the  process  name.
          When -f is set, the full command line is used.
```

In your case the process names are "python" and "sudo".

Answer (score 1):

A ha, I investigated it; so what you need to do is change it to

```
ps aux|grep main.py|awk '{print $2}'|sudo xargs kill -9
```

I updated my answer to reflect the requested code